# Optionally match part of a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

`(?P<a>\d+)\s(?P<b>.+)\s\((?P<c>.+)\)\s(?P<d>\d+)`

The strings I'm trying to match are:
`"1 Something (code) 123"`
Should match as `a=1`, `b=Something`, `c=code`, `d=123`

`"1 Something"`
Should match as `a=1`, `b=Something` (no match for `c` or `d`)

My expression doesn't match the second string.  How can I make the "(code) 123" part optional?

Comment: You could look at optional nested groups https://regex101.com/r/xkiyaY/1

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - it was the nesting that I hadn't understood.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested group, and make the part for group `d` optional. As `Something` is a single word, you can use `\S+` instead of `.+`

```
(?P<a>\d+)\s(?P<b>\S+)(?:\s\((?P<c>[^()\n]+)\)(?:\s(?P<d>\d+))?)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?P<a>\d+)\s(?P<b>\S+)` Match group `a`, a whitespace char and group `b`, where group 2 matches 1+ non whitespace chars instead of `.+`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s\((?P<c>[^()\n]+)\)` Match a whitspace char and group `c`
  - `(?:\s(?P<d>\d+))?` Optionally match group `d`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkiyaY/1)